# Why HttpEntity.toStrict has no variant without a timeout?

Tags: akka-stream, akka-http

Akka-http `HttpEntity.toStrict` is a way to consume an entity when the full body is required for later processing, but it does not have a variant without a timeout parameter.

It is quite easy to consume a body with `entity.dataBytes.runReduce(_ ++ _)` which does not have a timeout. But what are the consequences?

**Question #1**

If `HttpEntity.toStrict` times out, does akka-http close the connection immediately? Or still consuming the body discarding the data? Or what?

**Question #2**

If a body is consumed without a timeout (like with the above code), and the connection "hangs", are there any applicable timeout parameters in akka-http configuration? For client? For server? If connection "hangs" before starting the body, are there any applicable timeout parameters?

**Question #3**

If there is no global timeout, why `HttpEntity.discardBytes` does not have a similar timeout parameter?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> If HttpEntity.toStrict times out, does akka-http close the connection immediately? Or still consuming the body discarding the data? Or what?

It'd close the connection AFAIR, since it's counted as a failure which propagates down the stream (as well as up as a cancellation).

> If a body is consumed without a timeout (like with the above code), and the connection "hangs", are there any applicable timeout parameters in akka-http configuration? For client? For server? If connection "hangs" before starting the body, are there any applicable timeout parameters?

There's a full section about timeouts in the documentation: http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka-http/current/scala/http/common/timeouts.html
These include idle-timeouts which would trigger when connections "hang".

> If there is no global timeout, why HttpEntity.discardBytes does not have a similar timeout parameter?

There are global safety timeouts, most notably request timeouts and idle timeouts. All documented in the docs. http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka-http/current/scala/http/common/timeouts.html

`discardBytes` is really just convenience when you don't care at all about the entity. I guess we could add an overload with a timeout, it's the first time anyone asked for it to be honest though. You can easily add timeouts using the Akka Streams timeout stages anyway.

Comment: Thank you very much! It was unclear to me from the docs that idle timeout applies to both idling between requests and waiting for the next packet of the response being consumed. WRT discardBytes, I imagine there could be situation when the entity is expected to be very big, so dropping connection is cheaper then normal consuming.

Comment: You can always d connection, simply don't use discardBytes then - your call.